# Ошибка приложения

Tags: android

Простейший пример из учебника:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class ToDoList extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
    Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //Создаем массив для хранения списка задач
        final ArrayList<String> todoItems = new ArrayList<String>();
        //Создаем ArrayAdapter, чтобы привязать массив к ListView
        final ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, todoItems);
        //Привязываем массив к ListView
        myListView.setAdapter(aa);

    }
}
```

вылетает при запуске и на телефоне и на эмуляторе. Что не так? Тем более раньше все работало.
Вот разметка

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/myEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Новый пункт" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Добавить" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/myListView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Манифест

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.vitozzz.todo"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ToDoList"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Вот LogCat

```
04-09 10:41:07.380: D/AndroidRuntime(29652): Shutting down VM
04-09 10:41:07.380: W/dalvikvm(29652): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x2aac8578)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ru.vitozzz.todo/ru.vitozzz.todo.ToDoList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1581)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.Activity.findViewById(Activity.java:1647)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at ru.vitozzz.todo.ToDoList.<init>(ToDoList.java:14)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1573)
04-09 10:41:07.400: E/AndroidRuntime(29652):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: тут же не экстрасенсы сидят =) наверно, в манивесте не зарегистрировал.... ошибку выложи

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Было бы удивительно, если бы оно работало. Ошибка кроется в строках

```
final EditText myEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
Button addButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
```

Дело в том, что их можно вызывать только после того, как к создаваемому активити привязали какой-нибудь xml. Это происходит в строке `setContentView(R.layout.main);`. До этого момента получить view нельзя - их просто ещё не существует. Вставьте инициализацию этих полей сразу после `setContentView(R.layout.main);` и уберите модификатор final.

Comment: думаешь с учебника не правильно переписал? или это суровые челябинские учебники и ошибками?

Comment: я понятия не имею, что это за учебник. Может это для суровых австралийских детей, у которых все вверх тормашками (да. у них на карте мира Австралия вверху, а Евразия - внизу:) ).

Comment: Было бы удивительно, если бы Вы хоть попробовали скомпилить данный пример.
В этом куске я только объявляю переменные, чтобы использовать их во всем классе ToDoList, а не только в методе onCreate. И тут они даже не используются. Еслиб была такая ошибка как Вы написали, то компилятор бы выругался. Сейчас добавлю Layout и то что происходит после запуска для полной картины.

Comment: Весь пример мне не нужно компилировать, что бы увидеть проблему. Посмотрите в вывод logcat, Там очень хорошо видно NPE в 14 строке, где как раз и вызывается findViewById. Перечитайте мой ответ выше, исправьте код и убедитесь, что работать будет лучше.

Comment: > да. у них на карте мира Австралия вверху, а Евразия - внизу:)

пруф?

Comment: гугл отобрали? http://www.yakhnov.ru/go/note/2007/11/02/south-up-map/

Comment: Это сделано для смеха. А сегодня [девятое апреля](http://au.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091110022454AAXPsWS).

Comment: Все, понял! Надо было объявить переменные не инициализируя...